# how to create blank lines in a linux file

Tags: linux, file, awk, sed

This is my file, I want to create a blank lines after each character existing line, i know how to delete blank lines in a linux files by using sed /^$/ filename, i have  a big file like this  and i don't want to create a blank line manually

```
$ cat filename
Perl 5.18 is not binary compatible with Perl 5.16 and earlier
releases. In particular, do not attempt to use extensions or PPM
packages built for ActivePerl 1600 and older series builds with
ActivePerl 1800 series builds and vice versa. Please check
"Incompatible Changes" in perl5180delta for known source level
incompatibilities between the Perl 5.18 releases and the earlier
release series
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Perl 5.18 is not binary compatible with Perl 5.16 and earlier releases. In particular, do not attempt to 

use extensions or PPM packages built for ActivePerl 1600 and older series builds with ActivePerl 1800 

series builds and vice versa. Please check "Incompatible Changes" in perl5180delta for known source 

level incompatibilities between the Perl 5.18 releases and the earlier release series
```

Comment: I don't get your expected output, the formatting you set is quite horrible and I can't find a logic between your input and expected output at all. If you wish to add a blanck line after each carriage return you can do this `sed 's/$/\n\n/' filename` (replace each end of line ($) by two carriage return (\n))

Comment: @Tensibai i think they want to add a newline between where it ends on their terminal, so with the columns

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai , after removing one "\n" my output reached, needed a single blank line which are not having blank lines in a file i want to create there to better view for source codes

Comment: Aww, sorry. though sed would remove the existing carriage return when matching the end of line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In awk

```
awk '1;NF{print ""}' file
```

`1` evaluates to true and so prints the line.
`NF` Checks there is atleast one field(or character) on the line so won't print double blanks.
`{print ""}` prints a blank line.

---

Also if you wanted to print blank lines inbetween each line dependant on the width of the terminal then you could use

```
awk -vCol="$(tput cols)" '
    {while(length($0)>Col){print substr($0,0,Col)"\n";$0=substr($0,Col+1) }}1' file
```

Comment: Well Saar, Thanks , Could you please explain me the arguments detail

Comment: @DasD Should do, as long as you use `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`. Don't use `usr/bin/awk` though because it sucks.

Comment: Thanks A lot Man, Very Very Happy with your answers , by using nawk working on Solaris

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/[[:print:]]/ a\
' YourFile
```

or (depending your definition of *character existing line* )

```
sed '/[^[:space:][:cntrl:]]/ a\
' YourFile
```